# Unable to fetch all text file names recursively from a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I'm trying to fetch all text files from a directory in a recursive manner (i.e. search all sub-folders):

```
let fs = require("fs");

function getPathNames(dirName) {
    let pathNames = [];
    for (let fileName of fs.readdirSync(dirName)) {
        let pathName = dirName + "/" + fileName;
        if (fs.statSync(pathName).isDirectory())
            pathNames.concat(getPathNames(pathName));
        else if (pathName.endsWith(".txt"))
            pathNames.push(pathName);
    }
    return pathNames;
}
```

However, when I call `getPathNames(".")`, I get only the name of the first file.

It works fine if I take the return-value out of the function, and update a global variable instead:

```
let fs = require("fs");

let pathNames = [];

function getPathNames(dirName) {
    for (let fileName of fs.readdirSync(dirName)) {
        let pathName = dirName + "/" + fileName;
        if (fs.statSync(pathName).isDirectory())
            getPathNames(pathName);
        else if (pathName.endsWith(".txt"))
            pathNames.push(pathName);
    }
}
```

Does anyone spot anything wrong with the first method?

Comment: In the first method, you should have stored the value in `pathNames` after concating the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is not an in place mutation, but returns you a new array instead, so I would say you should do this instead

```
pathNames = pathNames.concat(getPathNames(pathName));
```